# Adding user role constraint redirects Browser to jsf.js script?

Tags: jsf, web.xml, jaas, j-security-check

My JSF form login was working with **Constraint 1** however when I added **Constraint 2** to my web.xml doing a submit on the form now takes me to a jsf javascript page. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I'm hoping this is a quick configuration mistake.

I would like only administrators to be able to access the /admin/* pages and only registered users to access the entire site included admin files. BTW after I see the java script page I can still navigate to the intended page in the browser, I just don't want the user to see the intermediate js page or need to know the target page URL.

**Constraint 1**

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Admin</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**Constraint 2**

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Users</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Here is the undesired url I am being redirected to:

```
javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development
```

Here is the start of the jsf.js.xhtml... which is displayed on Firefox

```
/**
 @project JSF JavaScript Library
 @version 2.0
 @description This is the standard implementation of the JSF JavaScript Library.
 */

/**
 * Register with OpenAjax
 */
if (typeof OpenAjax !== "undefined" &&
    typeof OpenAjax.hub.registerLibrary !== "undefined") {
    OpenAjax.hub.registerLibrary("jsf", "www.sun.com", "2.0", null);
}

// Detect if this is already loaded, and if loaded, if it's a higher version
if (!((jsf && jsf.specversion && jsf.specversion >= 20000 ) &&
      (jsf.implversion && jsf.implversion >= 3))) {

...
```

On Internet Explorer 8.0.7 I get this popup

[image: js_popup]

**Notes**

I'm using Firefox 10.0.4, IE 8.03, Glassfish 3.1 w JSF2.0 lib, j_security_check, and my login realm setup is similar to [this](http://blog.gamatam.com/2009/11/jdbc-realm-setup-with-glassfish-v3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
```

to your security.xml.
See comments below accepted answer [JSF with Spring security - Redirect to specified page after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456791/jsf-with-spring-security-redirect-to-specified-page-after-login)