# JSF with Spring security - Redirect to specified page after login

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, spring-security

I have a web application which uses JSF and Spring security is used for login and authorization.

When a user types in a specific page and he is not logged in, e.g. `localhost:8080/APP/page.xhtml`, the application redirects to the login page which is OK. After that, the user is logged in but the page he is redirected to is `index.xhtml` which is the default welcome page, and not to `page.xhtml`.

I want the following behaviour: user goes to `localhost:8080/APP/page.xhtml`, he is redirected to be logged in and after that he should be redirected to his desired page - `page.xhtml`.

**Edited** - Snippet of **spring-security.xml**:

```
 <security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_UNALLOCATED, ROLE_MANAGER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/management/" access="ROLE_MANAGER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/requests/" access="ROLE_UNALLOCATED, ROLE_EMPLOYEE, ROLE_TEAM_LEADER, ROLE_MANAGER"/>

    <security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" 
                          />
    <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            logout-success-url="/login.xhtml"
            invalidate-session="true"/>
</security:http>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Edit:

I thought it was because:

```
 <!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

from web.xml. I removed this but with the same result.

**Later edit:**

I just noticed a line in my custom loginController after `if (authenticationResponseToken.isAuthenticated())` which is almost surely the source of the problem:

The loginController:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "loginController")
@SessionScoped
@Controller
public class LoginController implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
IUserService userService;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

// save the current user after login to be able to inject it in other places
// as needed
private User currentUser;

/**
 * This action logs the user in and returns to the secure area.
 * 
 * @return String path to secure area
 */
public String loginUsingSpringAuthenticationManager() {
    // get backing bean for simple redirect form
    LoginFormBackingBean loginFormBean = (LoginFormBackingBean) FacesUtils
            .getBackingBean("loginFormBean");

    // simple token holder
    Authentication authenticationRequestToken = createAuthenticationToken(loginFormBean);

    // authentication action
    try {
        Authentication authenticationResponseToken = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(authenticationRequestToken);

        Authentication authCopy = null;
        final Object principal = authenticationResponseToken.getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof LdapUserDetailsImpl) {
            LdapUserDetailsImpl userImpl = (LdapUserDetailsImpl) principal;
            userImpl.getUsername();

            // here check if we already have a User with his DN in the DB
            // get the User by DN
            User u = userService.getUserByDn(userImpl.getDn());

            // if a user with this DN does not exist in the DB, create a new
            // one with the DN from LDAP and the default settings for a new
            // user
            if (null == u) {
                u = userService.createNewUserFromDn(userImpl.getDn(),
                        userImpl.getUsername());
            }
            // set the obtained user as the current user
            setCurrentUser(u);
            List<GrantedAuthority> grAuth = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            // after this, do the role authority stuff
            // here loop through user roles if he has more and
            if (null != u.getUserTeamRoles()) {
                for (UserTeamRole urt : u.getUserTeamRoles()) {
                    // here get role for every UserTeamRole
                    grAuth.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(urt.getRole()
                            .getName()));
                }
            }

            // add the above found roles to the granted authorities of the
            // current authentication
            authCopy = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authenticationResponseToken.getPrincipal(),
                    authenticationResponseToken.getCredentials(), grAuth);
        }

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authCopy);
        // ok, test if authenticated, if yes reroute
        if (authenticationResponseToken.isAuthenticated()) {
            // lookup authentication success url, or find redirect parameter
            // from login bean
            return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }
    } catch (BadCredentialsException badCredentialsException) {
        // FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(
        // "Login Failed: please check your username/password and try again.");
        // FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "Sample error message",
                        "Login Failed! Please check your credentials"));
    } catch (LockedException lockedException) {
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(
                "Account Locked: please contact your administrator.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
    } catch (DisabledException disabledException) {
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(
                "Account Disabled: please contact your administrator.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
    }

    return null;
}

private Authentication createAuthenticationToken(
        LoginFormBackingBean loginFormBean) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            loginFormBean.getUserName(), loginFormBean.getPassword());
    return usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
}
```

How can I redirect to the page I need? I have a loginBean which contains the user and password and I could add a redirectUrl but how do I find the previous url path?

Comment: Could you post your complete `http` configuration with `intercept-url`-s.

Comment: I added the whole security-http config

Comment: Try to debug `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and see if it is being executed and whether it redirects to proper url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Security [implements this logic for you](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L326) in the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter (typically using the concrete implementation of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) [by using the SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java#L60) (which uses the HttpSessionRequestCache under the covers). Since you have written a controller to authenticate (rather than using the built in support) you will need to implement this logic yourself. Rather than implementing all of the logic yourself, you can reuse the same classes Spring Security does.

For example, your LoginController might be updated as follows:

```
public class LoginController implements Serializable {
    // ... same as before ...
    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

    public String loginUsingSpringAuthenticationManager() {
        // ... just as you had been doing ...

        if (authenticationResponseToken.isAuthenticated()) {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)         
              FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)         
              FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

            SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

            return savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
        }

        // ... same as you had ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I did this, the problem is that my pages use PrimeFaces components. And probably because of that, the `savedRequest.getRedirectUrl` returns this always: `http://localhost:8080/APP/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces`. I inspected the source of the page and in the head component this same declaration is found: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/APP/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces">`

Comment: Is there any reason that you need this to be private? Unless you have a reason to secure the javascript (which is probably just a copy of jquery library), it seems as though you should probably make this URL public. Perhaps you meant to configure all resources as public (i.e. <security:intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>)?

Comment: Ok, I changed the pattern to `<security:http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/*" security="none"/>` and it's still the same.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is just SO formatting, but the pattern `/javax.faces.resource/*` does not match `/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces`. Ensure that you have pattern to have two `*` at the end. For example: `<security:http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none"/>`

Comment: That is perfectly right, it works with `/javax.faces.resource/**`. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

By default if `default-target-url` is not defined Spring Security tries to redirect to previous url, so you just need to remove `default-target-url` attribute from `form-login` tag.

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" />
```

**Update**

If your filter chain has the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` in it then it should cache HTTP request. So in your custom loginController you could try to get redirect url from this cached request.

```
RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
```

To inject request to your controller try:

```
private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
```

or

```
HttpServletRequest curRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) 
           RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()) .getRequest();
```

Comment: Did that, same result. after login it goes to index.xhtml

Comment: Which version of spring-security are you using? Also are you using default filter stack?

Comment: I'm using spring security 3.1.1. I'm not sure what is the default filter stack, I am using some <security:intercept-url> patterns to protect the pages and paths.

Comment: Problem is, I don't have the "request" and "response" params in my loginController

Comment: @AndaP: So inject them into your controller.

Comment: I'm not sure how to inject them, I did this: `SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(
    (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
      .getExternalContext().getRequest(),
    (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getExternalContext().getResponse());` and the url I get is: `http://localhost:8080/APP/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces`

Comment: @AndaP: Try `private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;` or `HttpServletRequest curRequest = 
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
.getRequest();`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" 
                         default-target-url="/index.xhtml" />
```

to

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" 
                         default-target-url="/page.xhtml" />
```

Comment: This would just make the application go to page.xhtml all the time instead of index.xhtml.

Comment: I know. Sorry @AndaP, I misread your question, just noticed now you wrote `eg` in front of the example address

Answer (score 0):

To have the behavior you described, you should add a spring security filter in your web.xml as following :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

And may be you have also to edit your spring-secruity.xml.
see this link for more information : [Spring Security with DelegatingFilterProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135558/spring-security-with-delegatingfilterproxy)

Check this discussion it looks like it's similar to your question, may be that helps you : http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?128480-Redirecting-to-original-(unauthenticated-page)-after-spring-security-openid-authentic

Comment: I actually have that configuration in my web.xml (without ERROR and INCLUDE cases) but it's still the same behaviour. I am not sure what I should modify from the link you gave me, it looks like I have the same config.

Comment: Do you use a custom authentication filter in your spring security configuration? I edit my post and add another link that may be helps you.

Comment: could you please edit the post and put your loginController declarration and the implementation of the method that contains if (authenticationResponseToken.isAuthenticated()).